# Convert factor to POSIXct

Tags: r, posixct

I have a date from a sql query that comes through as a factor and I would like to make it a POSIXct

```
f<- as.factor("01/03/2014 20:59:30")
f
class(f)
po<-as.POSIXct(f)
po
```

results

```
> f<- as.factor("01/03/2014 20:59:30")
> f
[1] 01/03/2014 20:59:30
Levels: 01/03/2014 20:59:30
> class(f)
[1] "factor"
> po<-as.POSIXct(f)
> po
[1] "0001-03-20 LMT"
```

you can see  "0001-03-20 LMT"  is not correct.  Do you know how to convert this factor to a POSIXct?

Thank you

Comment: Read the documentation of the functions you are using. You need to specify the format string.

Comment: `fac<-as.POSIXct(as.character(as.factor("01/03/2014 20:59:30")),format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to specify the format, since your date/time string is in a very non-standard and even ambiguous format:

```
r> as.POSIXct(f,format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S');
[1] "2014-03-01 20:59:30 EST"
```

See the documentation at http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/as.POSIXlt.html.

Comment: incidentally, you can look to [this page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime) for the format codes.

Answer (score 0):

You can make this much simpler by using `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)

# month-day-year hour-minute-second
mdy_hms(f, tz="EST")
[1] "2014-01-03 20:59:30 EST"
```